# How can I use progress bar while fetching data from server database located in web in c# winforms?

Tags: c#, winforms

After login process I want to load form1 with mdi.

In the Pageload event of the Form1 load database table data from web using JSon and saved to the local database.
Form1 pageload take lots of time.
When I execute my application the mdi form load first and after some time form1 is loaded.
I want to resolve this issue. This is my pageload event code.
Here get data from web and saved to the local database.
Then set the data to the controls in form1.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  string strUrlService = "http://.............................";
  string strUrlBranch = "http://......................";
  string strUrlOrigin = "http://.....";
  string strUrlEmployee = "http://.......";

  .............................
  GetServiceType(strUrlService);
  GetBranch(strUrlBranch);
  GetOrigin(strUrlOrigin);
  GetEmployee(strUrlEmployee);
  .............................

  SetServiceType();
  SetBranch();
  SetOrigin();
  SetEmployee();
  ......................

}
```

GetServiceType method definition. Using Json object get value from web. And saved this data to the local database.
//---------Get ServiceType from web database-------------

```
private void GetServiceType(string strUrl)
{
  ServiceType obj = new ServiceType();
  HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
  client.BaseAddress = new Uri(strUrl);
  client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
  client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
  HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(strUrl).Result;
  if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
  {
    var JsonResult = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer tmp = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
    obj = (ServiceType)tmp.Deserialize(JsonResult, typeof(ServiceType));
  }
  if (obj != null)
  {
    int count = obj.products.Count;
    int[] TxtID = new int[count];
    ..............................
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
      TxtID[i] = Convert.ToInt32(obj.products[i].id.ToString());
      ...............................
    }
    FunSaveServiceType(TxtID, txtService, txtCode, intDays);
  }
}
```

In SetServiceType() method retrieve data(which is fetched from web and saved to local database) from local database. And this data is set to the combo box in the form1.

```
//--------------set service type to Form1 combobox control-----------------
private void SetServiceType()
{
  DataTable dtService = new DataTable();
  dtService = GetServiceTypeFromDB();
  DataRow dr = dtService.NewRow();
  dr["ServiceType"] = "";
  dtService.Rows.InsertAt(dr, 0);
  cbServiceType.DataSource = dtService;
}
```

These are the process done before the form1 pageload event. These codes are working properly.

I am tried to set a progressbar and background worker in my mdi form. But it is not working properly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Progress reporting from background task](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1639969/progress-reporting-from-background-task)

Comment: Broken up large wall of text and corrected a few typos, but the question is still pretty low quality.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using .Net 4.5 you won't longer need a background-worker. You can use the new TPL (Task Parallel Library). What you need at first is a progressbar which you can show in a different form. You could also use your mainform for showing progress, but you should use the `Form1.Shown` Event than. This is fired if your form is up and running and your gui-components are loaded properly.

You can implement the progress logic in the Shown-Event as following:

```
private async void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   var progressHandler = new Progress<string>(value =>
   {
      //What to do if a Progress is reported?
      //For example set progressbar and labeltext
      progressBar.Step();
      label1.Text = value; //Value stores the string you send via Report (see at bottom method)
   });

   await InitializeServicesAsync(progressHandler as IProgress<string>);
}

private async Task InitializeServicesAsync(IProgress<string> progress)
{      
  await Task.Run(() =>
  {
    string strUrlService = "http://.............................";
    string strUrlBranch = "http://......................";
    string strUrlOrigin = "http://.....";
    string strUrlEmployee = "http://.......";

    GetServiceType(strUrlService);
    progress.Report("Getting Servicetypes done");

    GetBranch(strUrlBranch);
    progress.Report("Getting Branch done");

    GetOrigin(strUrlOrigin);
    progress.Report("Getting Origin done");

    GetEmployee(strUrlEmployee);
    progress.Report("Getting Employee done");

    SetServiceType();
    progress.Report("Setting ServiceType done");

    SetBranch();
    //Report further progress as often as you need

    SetOrigin();
    SetEmployee();
  });
}
```

Check out [this](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/09/taskrun-vs-backgroundworker-round-5.html) blogpost to learn more.

Comment: I tried this code. But get some errors. I could not fix that because i am new to this TPL. The following line shows an error 'await InitializeServicesAsync(progressHandler as IProgress<string>);' _Expected ;or=_

Comment: @Ajisha Editet again. The end of Task.Run... must be also enclosed with );.

Comment: The actual problem is not that.when i buil this code so many errors are reported.'await InitializeServicesAsync(progressHandler as IProgress<string>);
await Task.Run(() =>
progress?.Report("Getting Servicetypes done");'

Comment: @Ajisha Remove the ? and try to build it again. Further make sure you link the needed usings.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139348/discussion-between-ajisha-and-sebi).